# Python Click - variable options. Using context inside decorator

Tags: python, python-click

Here is a code sample:

```
import click
import functools

features = {
    "feature1": {
        "option11",
        "option77"
    },
    "feature2": {
        "option33",
        "option44"
    },
}

def wrapper(f, opt):
    @click.option(f"--{opt}")
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        return f(*args, **kwargs)

    return inner


def variable_options(f):
    # ctx = click.get_current_context() <-- this doesn't work
    # arg = ctx.parent.params.get("feature_name") <-- I need the context
    arg = "feature1" # 
    opts = features[arg]

    for opt in opts:
        f = wrapper(f, opt)
    return f

@click.group()
def cli():
    pass

@cli.group("do")
@click.argument("feature_name")
def do(feature_name):
    pass

@do.command("update")
@variable_options
@click.pass_context
def update(ctx, **kwargs):
    # this is what I want to get in the variable_options decorator
    print(ctx.parent.params.get("feature_name"))
    print(kwargs)
    exit(0)
```

What I'm trying to achieve is variable options. Where the option names are created at runtime based on what the previous command argument is, and a lookup is done in a dict to get the options. For example:

```
cli do feature1 update --option11
```

It's almost working, if I hardcode the parent contexts argument in the variable_options decorator, it works.

However I want to use the context here to get it dynamically. When I either try to use @click.pass_context on the decorator or click.get_current_context() inside the decorator - I get a runtime error that the context doesn't exist.

Is there an easier way to get variable options, and if not - how can I use the context inside the variable_options decorator? I would prefer not to use allow_extra_args as I want to be able to see all the options when the help is called

Thanks!

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce my idea and I don't have enough time to play around... nevermind, you could try to play around with a custom Command class and override it's get_params method. It is not documented, so take a look at the source code, but the method is fairly simple. It takes what you've got in self.params and add the help to it, if any. And it is invoked with the context as a param, so it is a good place to override what params you have.

Comment: Interesting - thanks for your help. I'll check it out

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. AFAIU, the options are predetermined based on the feature, as they are stored in a static dict. Then, what you want is simply defining nested groups, where each feature gets its group and its own update subcommand with the feature-specific options.

Comment: Yes, that would work; however that is a tremendous amount of code replication, my example here is an oversimplification. My solution below is working well in prod. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured the way I was trying to do it was impossible. If the context doens't exist - it doesn't exist. No way around that.

Here is my solution for dynamic options:

```
features = {
    "feature1": {
        "option1": {"type": bool, "help": "Option 1 help"},
        "option2": {"type": int, "help": "Option2 help"},
    },
    "feature2": {
        "option1": {"type": bool, "help": "Option 1 help"},
        "option2": {"type": int, "help": "Option2 help"},
    }
}

@click.group()
@click.argument("feature_name")
def cli(feature_name):
    pass

@cli.command(
    "update",
    context_settings=dict(
        allow_extra_args=True,
        ignore_unknown_options=True,
    ),
)
@click.pass_context
def update(ctx):
    cmd = ctx.parent.params.get("feature_name")
    if len(ctx.args) % 2 == 1:
        raise click.UsageError(
            f"Odd number of option values provided... is an option missing a value?"
        )
    # convert to dict
    opts = {ctx.args[i][2:]: ctx.args[i + 1] for i in range(0, len(ctx.args), 2)}
    if not opts:
        for opt, attrs in features[cmd].items():
            option = click.Option([f"--{opt}"], type=attrs["type"], help=attrs["help"])
            ctx.command.params.append(option)
        click.echo(ctx.get_help())
        exit(1)
    for key in opts:
        if key not in features[cmd]:
            raise click.UsageError(f"No such option --{key}\n")
```

This way you get an error if an option is passed that doesn't exist in the features dict, and you get useful help that matches the options for the specific value chosen prior